# I cannot install a very popular component, libmysqlclient-dev. What's wrong?

Tags: raspbian, apt, mysql

On an up to date stretch, I want to install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqld-dev, but apt tells me it was not available in my sources.

/etc/opt/sources.list looks like this:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
 deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
 deb https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
 deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
 deb-src http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

I wonder what could be wrong?

Comment: using `apt search libmysqlclient-dev` results in finding `default-libmysqlclient-dev` ... searching for `libmysqld` nothing is found - but then, I can't find anything that matches `libmysqld` on ANY Debian based system (amd64 or arm) - so it seems you want to install something, in that case, that doesn't exist at all

Comment: apt-get already fails at libmysqlclient-dev, it didn't even get to the second lib. That's probably even more trouble on the road ahead.

Comment: Not sure how relevant that is, of course it failed, because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian Stretch changed `libmysqlclient-dev` to `libmariadbclient-dev`.

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL that's more friendly in the open source world. It's compatible as a drop-in replacement, although you might find the setup steps have changed. It's covered in this [guide to installing WordPress on a Raspberry Pi](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress).